# How do I fix this Error in R: [.data.frame(newdata, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to recreate a random forest model from a paper, and the code doesnt seem to work, i am only just learning R and this is very much over my head, but i will try to explain as best I can.

The source code from the paper can be found here: [(https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0181347.s002&type=supplementary)]

The paper supplies two datasets: training and test, and then creates two subsets for each dataset (see bottom of text for head() of the data. [Data can be found in supplementary paper here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5521779/?report=classic)

(should be able to directly copy to a .csv) code is below:

```
sink("test.txt", split=TRUE)
print("#data process")
data_bin_train<-read.csv("training.csv", head=TRUE)
names(data_bin_train)
data_bin_test<-read.csv("test.csv", head=TRUE)
names(data_bin_test)
dspt_bin_train<-subset(data_bin_train,select=c(-Deamidation))
dspt_bin_test<-subset(data_bin_test,select=c(-Deamidation))
class_bin_train<-subset(data_bin_train, select=c(Deamidation))
class_bin_test<-subset(data_bin_test, select=c(Deamidation))

library("caret")
library("ROCR")
library("pROC")
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "CV",number = 10,returnResamp = "all", verboseIter = FALSE, classProbs = TRUE)
set.seed(2)
```

this bit works fine. Then the next bit of code is where i get the error:

```
library("randomForest")
print("#Random Forest binary class via caret (randomForest)")
caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10 <- train(Deamidation~., data=data_bin_train, method = "rf", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 10, trControl = fitControl)
caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10
varImp(caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10)

rf_bin_Preds <- extractPrediction(list(caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10),testX=dspt_bin_test[,1:13], testY=class_bin_test[,1])
```

Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected`
Any help would be amazing! The paper used R v 3.1.1 caret_6.0-35, whereas i am running updated versions of both, which is where i believe the error is coming from, but i'm not sure how to fix it, or to be honest what the error even is.

Thank you

TinoMass

below is the `sessionInfo() and Head() for the two data sets

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] randomForest_4.6-14 pROC_1.15.3         ROCR_1.0-7          gplots_3.0.1.1      caret_6.0-84       
[6] ggplot2_3.2.1       lattice_0.20-38    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3         pillar_1.4.3       compiler_3.5.3     gower_0.2.1        plyr_1.8.5         bitops_1.0-6      
 [7] iterators_1.0.12   class_7.3-15       tools_3.5.3        rpart_4.1-13       ipred_0.9-9        lubridate_1.7.4   
[13] lifecycle_0.1.0    tibble_2.1.3       nlme_3.1-137       gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.2       
[19] Matrix_1.2-15      foreach_1.4.7      rstudioapi_0.10    prodlim_2019.11.13 e1071_1.7-3        withr_2.1.2       
[25] stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.3        caTools_1.17.1.3   gtools_3.8.1       generics_0.0.2     recipes_0.1.8     
[31] stats4_3.5.3       grid_3.5.3         nnet_7.3-12        tidyselect_0.2.5   data.table_1.12.8  glue_1.3.1        
[37] R6_2.4.1           survival_2.43-3    gdata_2.18.0       lava_1.6.6         reshape2_1.4.3     purrr_0.3.3       
[43] magrittr_1.5       ModelMetrics_1.2.2 scales_1.1.0       codetools_0.2-16   MASS_7.3-51.1      splines_3.5.3     
[49] assertthat_0.2.1   timeDate_3043.102  colorspace_1.4-1   KernSmooth_2.23-15 stringi_1.4.3      lazyeval_0.2.2    
[55] munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

**training.txt**

```
PDB   `Residue #` `AA following A… attack_distance Half_life norm_B_factor_C norm_B_factor_CA norm_B_factor_CB norm_B_factor_CG
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 11BG           67 GLY                         3.84      1.02           1.46             1.46             1.36             1.38 
2 11BG           17 SER                         4.81     11.8            0.692            0.706            1.18             1.62 
3 11BG           71 CYS                         4.11     55.5            0.174            0.481            0.574            0.782
4 11BG           44 THR                         3.33     49.9           -1.24            -1.30            -1.35            -1.52 
5 11BG           94 CYS                         4.97     60              1.41             1.64             1.92             2.15 
6 11BG           27 LEU                         4.52    119             -0.898           -0.905           -0.820           -0.604
```

**test.txt**

```
PDB   `Residue #` `AA following A… attack_distance Half_life norm_B_factor_C norm_B_factor_CA norm_B_factor_CB norm_B_factor_CG
 <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                      <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 1ACC          713 GLY                         3.69      1.45           3.17             3.35              3.63             4.06
2 1ACC          719 GLY                         4.64      1.04           0.688            0.865             1.42             1.83
3 1ACC           28 PHE                         4.81     72.4            1.03             1.06              1.58             1.95
4 1ACC           52 ILE                         4.73    279              0.944            1.13              1.29             1.46
5 1ACC           85 HIS                         3.60      9.7            0.780            0.800             1.16             1.57
6 1ACC          104 LYS                         4.51     55.5            2.22             2.47              2.69             2.91
```

Comment: It will probably be easier to get help by providing only a minimal example that reproduces the problem. It is possible that the problem is due to `extractprediction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the two features:

"PDB"  - should not be used at all since its just the sequence accession.

"AA.following.Asn" - the test set does not contain all the levels as the train set.

```
levels(data_bin_train[,3])
#output
 [1] "ALA" "ARG" "ASP" "CYS" "GLU" "GLY" "HIS" "ILE" "LEU" "LYS" "MET" "PHE" "PRO" "SER" "THR" "TRP" "TYR" "VAL"

levels(data_bin_test[,3])
#output
 [1] "ALA" "ARG" "ASP" "GLU" "GLY" "HIS" "ILE" "LEU" "LYS" "PHE" "PRO" "SER" "THR" "TRP" "TYR" "VAL"
```

If one omits these two features from the sets the code runs and produces a sensible result

```
library(caret)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "CV",
                           number = 10,
                           returnResamp = "all",
                           verboseIter = FALSE,
                           classProbs = TRUE)
set.seed(2)
caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10 <- train(Deamidation~.,
                                   data = data_bin_train[,-c(1,3)],
                                   method = "rf",
                                   preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                                   tuneLength = 10,
                                   trControl = fitControl)

rf_bin_Preds <- extractPrediction(list(caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10),
                                  testX = data_bin_test[,-c(1,3)],
                                  testY = class_bin_test$Deamidation) 

head(rf_bin_Preds)
#output
  obs pred model dataType  object
1 Yes  Yes    rf Training Object1
2  No   No    rf Training Object1
3  No   No    rf Training Object1
4  No   No    rf Training Object1
5  No   No    rf Training Object1
6  No   No    rf Training Object1
```

Comment: Hey missuse, thank you for taking the time to help with this. yes column 1 and 2 area of no use (PDB and residue no) however, AA.following.ASN is very important ( meant to be the second biggest influence on outcome) so I need it to be included. why is it that the test needs to have as many levels as the training set? 

surely as long as all the levels in the test are contained in the training set it should work, i.e. no unique levels in AA.following.ASN it should work?

probably my lack of understanding in this.

Comment: also sadly when i run your code i get the error --- 

```Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : 
  missing values in newdata ```

I think a few N/A values have managed to sneak there way into the data_bin_train data set, and that might be causing the error.

Finally, sorry to ask so many Q, is the AA.following.ASN data type meant to be character or factor? does it make any difference for ML prediction

Thank you again!

Comment: The code I posted runs without issue in my R session. `caret_6.0-84`. `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)`. No NA values are there. `AA.following.ASN` should be a factor. Did you copy/paste my code and run it? I downloaded the supplementary file `pone.0181347.s001.xlsx` opened it in excel and saved the `training set` and `test set` tabs as `train.csv` and `test.csv`. Then I opened them in R using: `data_bin_train <- read.csv("train.csv")` and `data_bin_test <- read.csv("test.csv")`

Comment: Does `extractPrediction(list(caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10))` produce a result?

Comment: the NA's 100% my doing( not sure how though) anyway i remade the .csv fresh and it sorted that problem. 

Your code ran perfectly!, however i still cant get it to run when the AAA.following.ASN file is included.  I get no warning or errors. if i inspect the ```varimp(caret_rf_bin_randomf_cv10)
#output

                                Overall
Half_life                      100.000
ï..AA.following.AsnGLY  45.629
#etc... until...
ï..AA.following.AsnSER   6.618```

It seems like it is taking each value from AA.follow.ASN separately, instead of evaluating the list as a whole

Comment: also, again, cant thank you enough for all your help!

Comment: when the AA.following.ASN column is included. it errors with the same message asI originally got so it is this column causing the problems for sure, but as this is the second most important predictor, i need to find a way to include it, if you have any ideas?

Comment: scratch that, they dont use the AA.following.ASN in their model. just reevaluated the paper. they use peptide half life instead! Argh thats so annoying why include those in the .csv!, anyway! missue, thank you for your time and effort! you are a star!